# Different write and read operations with DRF

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, serialization

I am using Django Rest Framework for a project and I am running into a problem. When the frontend creates a Team they want to reference all relationships with an ID, but when getting the Team, they want the data from the relationship. How can I achieve this?

models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "team"
    team_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Organization(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "organization"
    organization_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Position(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "position"
    position_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="positions")

class Player(model.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "player"
    player_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position, related_name="players")
```

serializers:

```
class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ["team_id", "name", "organization", "positions"]

    positions = PositionSerializer(many=True)  # This is merely for output. There is no need to create a position when a team is created.
    organization = OrganizationSerializer() # Since an organization already exists I'd like to just give an organization_id when creating/editing a team.

# I don't think the other serializers matter here but can add them on request.
```

So when doing POST or PATCH on a team, I'd like the front end to be able to pass this payload

```
{
  "name": "My Team",
  "organization": 1
}
```

but when doing a GET on a team, I'd like the front end to receive this response.

```
{
  "team_id": 1,
  "name": "My Team",
  "organization": {
    "organization_id": 1,
    "name": "My Organization"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "position_id": 1,
    "players": [{
      "player_id": 1,
      "name": "Member 1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such situations define two serializers, one is for read operations and one is for write operations.

```
class TeamWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # see, here no nested relationships...
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ["name", "organization"]


class TeamReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ["team_id", "name", "organization", "positions"]

    positions = PositionSerializer(many=True)
    organization = OrganizationSerializer()
```

and now, use these two serializers properly in your views. For example, I hope you are using the **`ModelViewSet`** in views,

```
class TeamModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method.lower() == 'get':
            return TeamReadSerializer
        else:
            return TeamWriteSerializer
```